# How to use Messagebox in class library c#?

Tags: c#, .net, messagebox

How to use MessageBox in class library?

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MessageBoxes
{
    class ShowInfo
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

i can load MessageBox but can't have show property, MessageBox.Show("test"); <-- fail

Comment: You should post exact compiler errors when you get them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should **NOT** use a **Windows forms MessageBox** inside a **class library**. What if you use this library in an ASP.NET application. The MessageBox will be shown in Webserver. And your webserver will be waiting (hung) untill someone responds to that MessageBox in webserver.

An ideal design would be that you either return the message as string and deal with that string in caller specific way or throw an exception if thats what you want.

If you still want then here is your code corrected

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MessageBoxes
{
    class ShowInfo
    {
        public void ShowMessage(string msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oohh! i never learn asp.net before, i just trying to mod messageBoxes for desktop application. Btw thanks u telling me about this

Answer (score 2):

You have the call to messagebox outside any method.
This code cannot be compiled at all.

You should write

```
namespace MessageBoxes
{
    class ShowInfo
    {
        public void ShowUserMessage(string messageText)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(messageText);
        }
    }
}
```

and then call it after instancing an object of type ShowInfo

```
ShowInfo info = new ShowInfo();
info.ShowUserMessage("This is a Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional Answer to this Question:

After the Class Library Project has been created.

Right Click your Project `Add` > `New Item` > `Windows form`

it's done by adding reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually use the the class in the main form.

```
class ShowInfo
{
    public static void show()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

...

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowInfo.show();
    }
```

Comment: There is already declaration of windows forms namespace. What you did is exactly the same as user 's problem.

Comment: But mine hasn't! so i declared the namespace anyway. Why i tried to show is the use of the class in the form. And it works perfectly, so where's the problem? Cant you see the second code snippet?